# OpenGL ES 2.0 how to access LUT

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I've created a look up table for my fragment shader and I'm passing it in as a uniform float array:

```
#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require
precision mediump float;
uniform samplerExternalOES sTexture;
uniform float hueLut[360];
```

My program works fine on most devices but I ran across one device where I received this error:

```
Error: uniform variables in fragment shader do not fit in 224 vectors.
```

I've heard that this can be done using `texture2D` but I have no idea how to accomplish this in android.  What is the best way to access my LUT in the fragment shader to avoid these type of errors?

Comment: Does your GL implementation support [`GL_OES_texture_float`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_texture_float.txt)?

Comment: @genpfault I added the extension that I'm using to the question.  Is that something that I should add as well?

Comment: What actually goes into `hueLut`? What's the range of values and do they reproduce a continuous graph?

Comment: @Tommy It's basically a boolean map of 0 for false and 1 for true.

Answer (score 2):

Stop thinking of a texture as an image and just think of it as a 2d random-access array. Determine the minimum size that you can fit 360 values into which that implementation considers acceptable. 32x16 is likely to be inoffensive.

Pad and store your 360-value table as 512 bytes — `255` for `1` and `0` for `0`, as normal texture value scaling rules will apply — and submit as a `GL_LUMINANCE` texture, requesting nearest sampling.

Bind and supply the texture unit to a suitable sampler uniform, then sample as e.g. (hard coded to 32x16, written extemporaneously so check the logic):

```
lowp vec2 samplingLocation = vec2(
    (mod(index, 16.0) + 0.5) / 32.0,
    (index + 16.0) / (32.0 * 16.0)
);
lowp float oneOrZero = texture2d(tableUniform, samplingLocation);
```

Logic being:

- the x coordinate is that which wraps around — a later value in the lookup table may have a lower x location that an earlier value — therefore that needs to use only the low part of the index, which is achieved with a mod in GLSL ES 2.0 as there are no bitwise operations;
- the y coordinate is that which increases monotonically — a later value will always have a y location at least as high as an earlier value — but we don't need  explicitly to mask off the x because we're using nearest location sampling so anything inside the correct box will do;
- I've added 0.5 to the x index before dividing it by the width of the texture to aim for the centre of a texel, decreasing the risk of sampling error;
- I've added 16.0 to the y index before dividing it for the same reason, except that what's really happing there is `row = index / 32.0; y = (row + 0.5) / 16.0;` so the 0.5 gets multiplied up by the 32.0 due to otherwise being in the wrong place.

If you have a GL profiler you'll probably get a negative comment on dependent texture fetches, i.e. those which cannot be predicted ahead of running the fragment shader. The normal issue there is caching the correct part of the texture ahead of time. With a 32x16 texture you likely needn't be so worried.